# Getting Null value in parameter of Action method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, html.actionlink

**I am getting null value in the parameter of my action method.**

this is my action method

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ProjectData(int? formId)
     {
                if (formId == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }

                return View();

            }
     }
```

and this is my view of actionlink

```
@foreach (var projects in Model)
                {
                    int formId = Convert.ToInt32(@projects.FormId);

                <tr>
                    <td>@projects.Serial</td>
                    <td>@projects.ProjectName</td>
                    @*<td><a href="#">@projects.SurveyName</a></td>*@
                    @*<td>@Html.ActionLink(@projects.SurveyName, "ActionName", new { id = @projects.FormId })</td>*@

                    <td>@Html.ActionLink(@projects.SurveyName, "ProjectData" , "Home", new {id = formId}, null)</td>
                    <td>@projects.TotalSubmission</td>
                    <td>@projects.LastSubmissionTime</td>
                    <td>@projects.SubmissionToday</td>

                </tr>


                }
```

**I am using list of user defined type model:**

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC.ProjectInformation>
```

When I click on actionlink under the loop it should send id to the controller actionmethod but I get the parameter null always.
**Specific Actionlink:**

> @Html.ActionLink(@projects.SurveyName, "ProjectData" , "Home", new
>   {id = formId}, null)

I can see the id by debugging on the View but on controller actionmethod I cannot get that id value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ActionLink's routeValues object properties need to match the parameters of the controller action.

Currently it is

```
new { id = formId }
```

which would not match the parameter of the `ProjectData`

```
public ActionResult ProjectData(int? formId)
```

Update to match

```
@Html.ActionLink(@projects.SurveyName, "ProjectData" , "Home", new {formId = formId}, null)
```